# Could not push integer value in Stack. Can not convert char to int

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi I am working on a simple code wherein I am trying to push integer into a integer array from a string.
Below is my code:

```
            /*
                Input:3[a2[b]]  Output: abbabbabb
            */
            Stack<int> intChar = new Stack<int>();
            Stack<string> strChar = new Stack<string>();
            string output = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the string of chars");
            string input= Console.ReadLine();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                char c = input[i];
              
                if(Char.IsDigit(c)) 
                {
                    intChar.Push(input[i]);
                }
```

that if condition is taking up wrong values and I think it is taking up the ascii value of the character and pushing in the ascii value of the same. below us the screenshot of the debug window.

[image: Debug window and values of the variables]

I want to check the entire string and push the integer and char values to their respective Stacks. Please suggest me where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: you're trying to add a `character`-variable to a stack that is explicitly specified to only accept `integer`-variables. (which is what your error message is telling you). you have to either _convert_ it (if you want the ascii value of the char), or _parse_ it (if you want the number you see in the string).

Comment: I tested it , everything works fine.

Comment: @Serge it pushes ascii value into the in stack. Rather it should push the int value

Comment: You have to post all code then. I can't see how you use strChar

Comment: Subtract 48 from _c_ and push the result. Ascii value for '0' is 48, for '1' is 49 and so on.

Comment: @webDC what is a difference ? can you explain pls, post it in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently type char is converted to ascii code. You have to use string to get the real number. Try this

```
if (Char.IsDigit(c)) intChar.Push( Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString()) );
```

another way is to use GetNumericValue function. Since it returns double, it needs to be cast to int.

```
if (Char.IsDigit(c)) intChar.Push( (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c) );
```